# What "to infinitive" modifies in this sentence?

Tags: to-infinitive

> The fund will go a long way to solve their problem.

I have a question on what **"to solve their problem"** modifies in the sentence.

I think this can modify either **"a long way"** or **"the whole sentence, the fund will go a long way"**, but I'm not sure which way is technically correct in meaning.

If it modifies **"a long way"**, **"a long way to solve their problem"** seems to have to modify **"go"** as an adverbial phrase, but on the other hand, if it modifies **"the whole sentence"**, it should mean like **"in order to solve their problem**, or **"so as to solve their problem"**.

Comment: We'd normally say "The fund will go a long way towards solving their problem".

Comment: @BillJ I think your sentence is much better than that, but I'd like to hear your opinion on the question.

Comment: I think it's a complement of "way".